# How do I prevent my crawler from being shown in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, web-crawler

I have an app that checks your website for issues like broken links and SEO issues.  Since a couple of weeks, the actions of this crawler show up in the Google Analytics accounts for the visited websites. I would like to prevent that, because it messes up the GA reports of my users.

The crawler is not executing any javascript and has this user agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Appname Crawler; +https://www.nameofmyapp.co/crawler)

I would expect that GA would be smart enough to recognize that this is a crawler. It used to, but since a few weeks GA counts the visits of my crawler as actual visits, even when the Bot And Spider Filtering option is on.

How do I prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 0):

Under Admin > View settings you could add an Filter with an UserAgent you want to exclude.
Alternatively your Bot should block the GA Script, so your visit should not be recognised.

Answer (score 0):

Found it: my bot is using the Google Pagespeed API to check how fast the page is. Those requests end up in GA.